# How to import python module located in different folder?

Tags: python, import, module

I am attempting to access predownloaded API python modules in a different folder than my current directory. The file path of the modules I want to access is:
***"C:\Program Files\Bentley\Engineering\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition V8\python\ram_concept"***.

I have tried sys.path.append and `sys.path.insert` with any luck.
Is it possible to import these files to my main.py by importing them from the separate folder as opposed to copy pasting to the same project folder that main.py resides in?  If so, how?

**Here is my code:**

```
import sys
import requests

raw_path = r"C:\Program Files\Bentley\Engineering\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition V8\python"

sys.path.insert(1, raw_path)

from ram_concept.concept import concept
```

**Corresponding error message:**

```
C:\Users\austin.paxton\PycharmProjects\2021.35_Howard\RAM_test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/austin.paxton/PycharmProjects/2021.35_Howard/RAM_test/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\austin.paxton\PycharmProjects\2021.35_Howard\RAM_test\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ram_concept.concept import concept
ImportError: cannot import name 'concept' from 'ram_concept.concept' (C:\Program Files\Bentley\Engineering\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition\RAM Concept CONNECT Edition V8\python\ram_concept\concept.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: Does `...\ram_concept\concept.py` contain a global function/class/variable named `concept`? Share the contents of the file?

Comment: https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-create-a-python-package/